# how to connect aws ec2 using Xshell 6

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passphrase

i have stuck at `Xshell6` where i am trying to connect `Aws EC2` `Ubuntu` instance. I have upload `.pem key` in User key Manager, prompt new session, putted Name, Hostname, Protocol as 22. In authentication, using public key as method, username as `ec2-user` and picking public key (.pem file)

Still it is asking **passphrase**. Can someone help how to connect Amazon EC2 instance by using passphrase ?

Comment: Can you try ssh with sudo like `sudo ssh -i /home/test.pem ubuntu@host` ?

Comment: ``ssh -i "awscav.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-232-160-30.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com``


``Host 'ec2-13-232-160-30.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com' resolved to 13.232.160.30.``
``Connecting to 13.232.160.30:22...``

Connection established.
To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.
Connection closing...Socket close.

Connection closed by foreign host.

``Disconnected from remote host(ec2-13-232-160-30.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22) at 10:49:32.``

Comment: By any chance did you modified /etc/ssh/sshd_config ?

Comment: Not yet, first thing i have launched ``EC2`` from ``AWS`` Console and connecting through ``Xshell6``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username for AWS Ubuntu instance is `ubuntu`, you are using username as `ec2-user` which is for the Amazon Linux AMI.

So, put the user as `ubuntu` and you'll get logged in.